# PrimeNG datatable globalFilter restictions

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

Is there a way to restrict some fields from the globalFilter search?

in my code i have a dataTable with multiple columns, some of those columns are timestamps,
createTime, endTime, modificationTime.

i use template like this:

```
<p-column field="modificationTime" header="Last modified" [sortable]="true">
  <template let-col let-service="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <span>{{ service.modificationTime | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" }}</span>
  </template>
</p-column>
```

to display it in a readable format.

But
when i search in the globalFilter i get results regarding the timeStamp and not the displayed format.
can i ignore those fields in the globalFilter search.
(i cant do the formatting before binding, in this way the sort would work wrong).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No

I've created a "feature request" on their GitHub : https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4157

UPDATE: it should be present in next release